# Need details of tables that store Zip codes?

Tags: magento2, zipcode

I want to use **cities** instead of **zipCodes**. Need details of table/s where I could insert *city* values instead of *Zip codes*.

Answer (score 0):

Its not in the database, but in zip code mask XML file.

zip_codes.xml

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_zip.html

Answer (score 0):

> The table which stores details of zip codes is **customer_address_entity**,there is field **postcode**(Zip/Post Code) which has zip codes.